# How to deal with missing fields in react.js

Tags: javascript, json, rest, design-patterns, reactjs

Let's assume that there is an app written in react.js. It fetches single json through rest api and pass some properties to children components.

What is a proper way to handle potentially missing attributes of json and stuff? I probably should check in every component if props are there, and fill state with proper structure but filled with empty data, something like this:

```
var SomeComponent = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    someNestedStructure: {
      foo: {
        bar: null,
        baz: null
      },
      morenested: {
        something: '',
        andEvenMoreNested: {
            somethingb: ''
        }
      },
      somedata: {
        id: null
      },
      somedataaa: {
      }
    }
  }
},
componentDidMount: function() {
  //call rest api and set new state depending on what is inside json
  //check every required field to pass to children compoents
},
render: function() {
  return (
    <div>
        <ComponentUsingNEsteStructure data={this.state.someNestedStructure.moreNested}/>
        <ComponentThatNeedsEverythign data={this.state.someNestedStructure} />
        <SomeOtherComponent some={this.sate.somedataaa} />
    </div>
  );
}
});
```

But I guess it generate a lot of json related structures inside code and a lot of ifs.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't specific to React.  What you want is deep extend.  This is available on npm as [deep-extend](https://www.npmjs.org/package/deep-extend)

The usage is like this:

```
var defaultsForThing = {
  foo: '',
  bar: {
    baz: true,
    quux: null
  }
};

// make a defaulting function
var defaultThing = deepExtend.bind(null, defaultsForThing);

// fetch some data which might be missing fields
$.getJSON('/api', function(data){
  var fixed = defaultThing(data);
  doSomethingWith(fixed);
});
```

Here's the deepExtend function (but prefer the [linked to module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/deep-extend))

```
var deepExtend = module.exports = function (/*obj_1, [obj_2], [obj_N]*/) {
    if (arguments.length < 1 || typeof arguments[0] !== 'object') {
        return false;
    }

    if (arguments.length < 2) return arguments[0];

    var target = arguments[0];

    // convert arguments to array and cut off target object
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

    var key, val, src, clone, tmpBuf;

    args.forEach(function (obj) {
        if (typeof obj !== 'object') return;

        for (key in obj) {
            if ( ! (key in obj)) continue;

            src = target[key];
            val = obj[key];

            if (val === target) continue;

            if (typeof val !== 'object' || val === null) {
                target[key] = val;
                continue;
            } else if (val instanceof Buffer) {
                tmpBuf = new Buffer(val.length);
                val.copy(tmpBuf);
                target[key] = tmpBuf;
                continue;
            } else if (val instanceof Date) {
                target[key] = new Date(val.getTime());
                continue;
            } else if (val instanceof RegExp) {
                target[key] = new RegExp(val);
                continue;
            }

            if (typeof src !== 'object' || src === null) {
                clone = (Array.isArray(val)) ? [] : {};
                target[key] = deepExtend(clone, val);
                continue;
            }

            if (Array.isArray(val)) {
                clone = (Array.isArray(src)) ? src : [];
            } else {
                clone = (!Array.isArray(src)) ? src : {};
            }

            target[key] = deepExtend(clone, val);
        }
    });

    return target;
}
```

One thing I might change in that function is that it doesn't satisfy this case well:

```
var defaults = {
  a: [{b: 0, c: 0}]
};

var obj = {
  a: [{b: 1}, {b: 2}, {c: 3}]
};

deepExtend(defaults, obj);
```

For the purpose of fixing json responses, you'd want to end up with the following, however this isn't technically a deep default (it's schema coercion).

```
{
  a: [{b: 1, c: 0}, {b: 2, c: 0}, {c: 3, b: 0}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the large, nested object at the top level by using [getDefaultProps](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#default-prop-values) to assign defaults to each component's props to cater for missing values. You could move the REST API access to the parent and pass the results to the children via their props (you'd have to use the parent's state as a trigger to re-render the child on getting the AJAX response, though).